# Android Handler handleMessage

Tags: android, networking

Can someone tell me why I am getting network on main thread exception in `handleMessage`

Comment: Try using AsyncTasks, which is much easier and cleaner.

Comment: maybe it is but the problem is if I use `onPictureTaken` in `doInbackground` in `AsyncTask` I  am gettin the same error with `onPictureTaken`

Comment: could you share the logcat logs?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Without those informations it's really hard to tell where the error can come from.

Answer (score 0):

Because you create instance of handler in main thread and in work on it. And in heandler you try to create socket connection (internet conection) in main thread.

```
 /**
     * Default constructor associates this handler with the {@link Looper} for the
     * current thread.
     *
     * If this thread does not have a looper, this handler won't be able to receive messages
     * so an exception is thrown.
     */
    public Handler() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are encountering the exception due to   `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Try using a new thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         showToast(MessageBuilder.SUCCESSFUL_COMMENT);
       }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your handler in the background. You can use `Looper` for this. 
Refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html.

You could try this:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            Looper.prepare();

            handler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    try {
                        String tmp = msg.obj.toString();
                        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
                        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, serverPort);
                        OutputStream outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outStream);
                        writer.write(tmp);
                        writer.flush();
                        InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
                        byte[] xxx = new byte[20];
                        int count = inStream.read(xxx);
//          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        outStream.flush();
                        outStream.close();

                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        Looper.myLooper().quit();
                    }
                }

            };
            handler.removeCallbacks(this);
            Looper.loop();
        }
    };

    thread.start();
```

Also you are showing a `Toast` in your handler which will cause RuntimeError. Please remove the Toast from the handler.

Comment: ok, how it should look like ? can you show me this based on my code ?

Comment: I was trying to solve this on my won but I always have 'network on main thread exception' caused by Inputstream

Comment: @SimpleCoder I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: I have updated code based on your example and the problem is that I don't get any errors(logcat shows nothing) but when I press the button picture is made but not sent but when I close the application then picture is send.... its weird ?

Comment: and with commented `InputStream` part after pressing a button picture is made and sent, but I need to receive response from server so I need `InputStream`